# Laravel eloquent model Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, model, eloquent

This is my web.php in routes folder

```
Route::get('/task',function(){

        $task = App\Task::all();

        return view('task',['task' => $task]);
    });
```

This is my Task model, Task.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tasks extends Model
{
    //

}
```

I dont know why when i go /task , an error shown

> Class 'App\Task' not found

Can someone help me? I am new to Laravel

Comment: You should really put the logic into a controller rather than within the Routes web.php file.

Comment: Try this: `$task = \App\Tasks::all();`

Comment: @Option, yea, i will change that..

Comment: @HirenGohel , Alright, I will try

Comment: @HirenGohel, Thansk man, but still cant worked..

Comment: @Wei, if you use the controller add `use App\Task` under the namespace and you won't have any problems.

Comment: @ Option, sure i will try controller later on, thanks ur advice man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top of your web.php route file mention model

```
use App\Task;
```

and then use

```
Route::get('/task',function(){

        $task = App\Task::all();

        return view('task',['task' => $task]);
    });
```

Comment: @WeiKang check your model name and class name as same.

Comment: @WeiKang  good practice to use same name as model and class name

Answer (score 1):

Here is your fix, you have model with name `Tasks` not `Task`

`$task = App\Tasks::all();`

Hope this helps

Comment: what's the issue now ?

Comment: `use App\Tasks` add this to the top of file.

Answer (score 1):

```
use App\Task;
add it in your controller where you want to fetch data
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution that might help others is that the model file doesn't have .php in the filename. So in this case the model filename would be Task 
instead of Task.php